# How to separate existing code into presenter vs model for implementing MVP and Unit Testing

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, refactoring, mvp, legacy-code

I am trying to refactor an existing WinForms app to use the Model-View-Presenter (MVP) pattern for the first time so that I can then write Unit Tests. I have a lot of existing code like the following which does not have a UI/View to worry about but I need to write Unit Tests for this validate function without actually causing a database call. How should I split this up for Model vs Presenter classes? I am uncertain how to extract a model class from this:

```
Friend Sub ValidateAmountNotEntered(exp() As String, paramString As String, exp2() As String, paramString2 As String)
    Dim SqlStmt As String = "[Long complex parameterized query to 
        Select values From 4 tables (T1 T2 T3 T4) 
        Where T1.Column1 = ?
        And T2.Column1 In (" & paramString & ")  
        And T4.Column1 In (" & paramString2 & ")  ]"

    Dim com As New OdbcCommand With {
        .Connection = New OdbcConnection(CommonUtilities.GetODBCConnectionString()),
        .CommandText = SqlStmt
    }

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CStr(GlngNum))
    For Each parameter As String In exp2
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", parameter.Replace("'", String.Empty))
    Next
    For Each parameter As String In exp
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", parameter.Replace("'", String.Empty))
    Next

    Dim adap As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(com)
    Dim rsRates As New DataSet("dsl")
    adap.Fill(rsRates)
    For Each iteration_row As DataRow In rsRates.Tables(0).Rows
        AddErrorItem(iteration_row.Item("T1.Column1"), "R", "Amount for " & iteration_row.Item("T4.Column1").Trim() & "; " & iteration_row.Item("T3.Column1").Trim() & " not entered")
    Next iteration_row
End Sub
```

Can anyone guide or provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract out a dedicated data access layer that performs all interactions with the database. You can then mock that DAL in any tests of higher layers. For instance, if you have a `DataAccess` class that has a `GetData` method that returns a `DataTable` populated from the database, tests on your business logic can mock that method of that class and return a canned `DataTable`, so no database access is required.

The model is then the data itself. If you're using standard ADO.NET then you don't need a dedicated model as you're already using `DataTables` and, possibly, `DataSets`. You might choose to create your own dedicated model classes and then map between those and the `DataTables`.

The presenter is then the broker between the data access layer and the presentation layer. It just moves the data between the view and the data access layer.